# Error al guardar la información de etiqueta

Tags: bug, estado-no-reproducido

Estoy tratando de editar la información de la etiqueta para Python pero por alguna razón me sale el error cada vez que intento guardarla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego me dice que espere 30 segundos pero el error vuelve a ocurrir.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No habrá sido un error momentáneo en tu conexión? Si guardás el texto, volvés a cargar la página y reintentás, se reproduce el error?

Comment: Bueno, en este momento tengo la página abierta y sigo intentando sin éxito. Déjame probar lo que mencionas cargando la página

Comment: Como dice @Mariano puede ser algo con tu conexión, ayer edite una etiqueta sin problemas.  Voy a intentar editar otra ahora.

Comment: @Mariano recargué la página pero el problema persiste

Comment: Por razones aún desconocidas ahora si me ha dejado guardar después del millonésimo intento

Comment: @CésarBustíos cambiaste algo en el texto? porque yo sigo intentando y aún no me deja publicar.

Comment: @Mariano no cambie nada, seguía insistiendo hasta que por fin me dejó

Comment: @Konamiman Para agregar a tu cambio a NO-REPRO, sólo pasó en un momento al principio del beta (muy frecuente). No volví a encontrar ese error

Comment: @César quizás te interese [¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3210/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OBSOLETO

Esta publicación tiene datos que sucedían antes y no aplican actualmente

---

---

---

#### No es una respuesta, pero lo pongo en caso de que César quiera agregarlo

Originalmente [pensé que era un error de conexión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/91/error-al-guardar-la-informaci%c3%b3n-de-etiqueta#comment150_91), pero pude reproducirlo:

Editando un texto largo (6242 caracteres) en https://es.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/171 obtuve el mismo error, con:

```
GET https://es.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/edit-tag-wiki/submit/171 500 (Internal Server Error)
    send                        @ jquery.min.js:4
    f.extend.ajax               @ jquery.min.js:4
    r                           @ wmd.es.js?v=4db30bdb37b1:3
    (anonymous function)        @ wmd.es.js?v=4db30bdb37b1:3
```