# ¿Cómo etiquetamos las preguntas de Django?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Las preguntas de [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) ¿van etiquetadas como [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)?

Le pregunto a la comunidad de Python, ¿qué conviene? ¿Qué sería lo mejor y por qué?

Se me ocurren 3 posturas (me dirán si hay más):

1. Todo lo de [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) va como [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) porque es el mismo lenguaje. Por más que cambie el framework, es preferible que estén agrupadas, funciona mejor en las búsquedas, y ambas etiquetas se benefician una de la otra. Además, sirve para poder recibir notificaciones de una sola, o involucrar a alguien que no use Django, pero que igual pueda responder una pegunta que no esté relacionada al framework.
2. Etiquetar como [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) todas las preguntas de [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) que traten sobre un problema de código en general, pero dejar solamente [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) en aquellas que traten sobre funciones específicas del framework... Aunque esto puede ser un poco más complicado al determinar el límite, y más aún con preguntas donde un revisor o incluso el propio autor de la pregunta aún no sabe por dónde va la solución.
3. Separemos las aguas. Dejemos a [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tranquila, que es una comunidad grande a la que no tiene sentido molestar con etiquetas de un framework que pueden no dominar. Así se facilita la búsqueda de código Python que no dé resultados inservibles porque son de Django y viceversa... Aunque así también estaríamos empezando a duplicar algunas preguntas que pueden ser independientes del framework y tienen la misma solución. Fácilmente se puede cerrar como duplicado (porque el problema no era de Django sino de Python), pero algunas veces el ejemplo en Django puede ayudar más a quien pregunta.

---

Todo esto me surgió a partir de [una sugerencia de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/140721/revisions) que opté por editar para agregarle [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), siguiendo la recomendación [en la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info):

> Esta etiqueta se usa con preguntas relacionadas con el núcleo del framework Django: modelos (querysets, instancias, migraciones, agregación), vistas (URLs, CBV, archivos), plantillas, formularios (Form API y widgets), el área de admin; en temas de i18n, despliegue y unicode. **Se recomienda usarla junto con la etiqueta "python" y una etiqueta especializada** (ej. django-modelos, django-vistas). Se debería incluir un ejemplo mínimo, completo y reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi opinión basada en lo que he visto es que casi nadie se lee los consejos de uso de una etiqueta, incluso los hay que ni se leen la descripción.

Quien conoce [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) ya debería saber su relación con [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). El problema es el inverso, alguien que viene buscando preguntas de [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) ¿cómo descubre que [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) es un framework relacionado?.

En el buscador de etiquetas, [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) y [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) no están relacionadas de modo que si buscas una etiqueta no sale la otra. Tal vez sería algo a mejorar.

En este momento, la única forma disponible de relacionar ambas etiquetas es que ambas figuren en la pregunta. Siempre es posible ignorar las preguntas etiquetadas como [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) si no te interesan.

Mi voto sería la **opción 1**, poner todas la etiquetas que puedan estar relacionadas. Sin embargo, procuraría que el número total de etiquetas fueran demasiadas. Recomendaría no usar más de 3 etiquetas para *"posicionar"* la pregunta: una principal, [python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), una más específica, [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) y otra relacionada, [mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). Si hay que especificar más, [django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) pasaría a ser la etiqueta principal y añadiría dos más.

Pero lo dicho, nadie se lee las recomendaciones de uso. Así que lo que digamos aquí no va a servir de mucho.

Comment: Es cierto que casi nadie lee... Pero quizás nos sirva a los pocos que sí ;-) Al menos para llegar a un acuerdo de qué es lo que se *debería* hacer. Luego podrá desvariar, pero sabemos cuál es el ideal. Gracias por tu opinión, me importaba mucho el feedback de los que están día a día en estas preguntas.

Comment: Piensa una cosa más: con la etiqueta python no nos pusimos de acuerdo en usar una sola para python3. Si la pregunta es más de python que de django, las etiquetas serían "python", "python-3.x" y "django" como mínimo, ya que no se puede asumir que todo el mundo sepa qué versión de python usa django. Definitivamente, no hay una solución que me convenza.

Comment: Quizás pase lo mismo con esta pregunta, pero no voy a rendirme sin haberlo intentado! :-)

Comment: Si me tengo que decantar mi voto sería también por la opción 1. Es verdad que hay preguntas que son muy específicas de Django que solo alguien con conocimientos profundos del framework puede responder pero muchos otros casos son en realidad problemas más genéricos del lenguaje que alguien con conocimientos de Python puede abordar. Lo "ideal" sería la opción 2, pero a la hora de la verdad la clasificación va a ser muy subjetiva, más aún para el OP que en muchos casos no tiene ni idea del origen de su problema.

Comment: Además separar las etiquetas en nuestra comunidad  (sin las dimensiones de SO) puede implicar que preguntas de Django queden más desatendidas de lo que deberían  al no recibir la atención de los que solo siguen a Python (p.e me he encontrado preguntas buenas con solo la etiqueta python2.x con apenas atención por no incluir la etiqueta principal). En definitiva, en mi opinión, por mucho que sea un framework con mucha entidad y con una comunidad propia no veo razones para tratarlo de forma distinta a casos como PyQt, Kivy, NumPy, Pandas, BeautifulSoup...